# AJAX request not returning data back to the select option box

Tags: php, html, ajax

Goodday, recently ive tried to learn AJAX. Ive made up an example that captures the data selected from the 1st dropdown box and filter into the 2nd dropdown box. However, the AJAX request doesnt seem to run.

**HTML**

```
<?php include 'conn.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
AJAX for extensions!
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'fetch_data.php',
        data: {
            get_option:val
        },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementByID("owner_id").innerHTML=response;
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP for Extensions</p>
<center>
<div id="select_box">
    <select name="department" id="department" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <?php 
        $sql="SELECT Department1 FROM PIC_Approval";
        $result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
        while($row=odbc_fetch_array($result)){
            $department=$row['Department1']; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $department;?>"><?php echo $department;?></option>
    <?php  }
    ?>
    </select>

    <select name="ownerid" id="owner_id">
    </select>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
    echo $_POST['get_option'];
 $department = $_POST['get_option'];
 $sql1="SELECT Owner_I_Employee_ID FROM masterlist1 WHERE Department1='$department'";
 $result1=odbc_exec($conn,$sql1);
 while($row=odbc_fetch_array($result1))
 { 
     $id=$row['Owner_I_Employee_ID']; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;?></option>
<?php   
 }
 exit;
}
?>
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the Request. I followed as in the tutorials i found online. I am using odbc.

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you're not looking for problems. Please use the Console and Network tools in your browser to check for errors and debug the Ajax. Also enable error logging in PHP so you can detect server side errors. Learn to debug. In this case there isn't a lot we can tell just from looking at the code alone.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry sir, i will try to learn from my mistakes. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's not a mistake, it's just clearly something you haven't learned yet. You need to learn to debug at the same time you learn to write code, otherwise you can't ever solve simple issues in your program. If you still have a problem with the code after you have debugged it and can't solve it yourself or by googling, then edit your question to include the information you have found, and then maybe we can help you more

Comment: Hi Steve, yup ADyson is right, you did most of thing good, but you lack a special part in your question... that is, what is the error? it would be difficult to the community to set an environment equals to yours, and we may not be able to reproduce the same issue you had.

So as a friendly advise, when making a question, add logs and errors in addition to your code.

and welcome to the community BTW

Comment: @WistonCoronell Thanks for the advice Winston. I will bare in mind when i post new questions here in future times. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's because

```
document.getElementByID("owner_id")
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("owner_id")
```

because JavaScript is case-sensitive. The code works fine after the error is fixed.